# Azure premium SQLDB with 2TB memory

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-sql-database

In the Azure Pricing for single data base [see link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/)

It states that: More than 1 TB of storage in the Premium tier is available in the following regions: East US 2, West US, West Europe, Southeast Asia, Japan East, Australia East, Canada Central, Canada East, Germany Central, US Gov Virginia. More widespread availability is planned. In other regions, the storage max in the Premium tier is limited to 1 TB.

I am trying to set 2 TB of memory with premium, 125 DTU, When i create the SQL Data base, but i can't go beyond 1 TB.

I am in west Europe

**I don't want to use the default 4 TB with the 1750 DTU since its very expensive and i don't need 4 TB**

See image...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should select more DTU, then we can select more storage.

> a 4TB increase of storage limits for Premium P11 and P15

Like this:

[image]

Comment: I want to use 2 TB size in SQL data base with 125 DTU in west Europe - can i do it ?

Comment: @asaf For now, Azure does not support 125 DTU with 2TB storage, if we want to use 2TB storage, we should use P11 (1750 DTU).